# Rails with 3 Cascading Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, cascading

I have 3 cascading drop down lists named; Country, City and District. The relation between them is the following;

```
#country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :districts, :through => :cities
end

#city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :districts
end

#district.rb
class District < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I have a problem that, when I choose Country and City at the network tab of chrome response seems correct but the list does not renew it self. Here is what it looks like;
[image]

So I select France - Nice but the last drop down has to show 5,6,7,8 instead of 1,2,3,4. However, at the response tab it seems fine;

[image]

But whatever the city or country I select response is fine but it does not show at the drop down list.

Here is my `controller`;

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @countries = Country.all
    @cities = City.where("country_id = ?", Country.first.id)
    @districts = District.where("city_id = ?", City.first.id)
  end

  def show
    @city = City.find_by("id = ?", params[:trip][:city_id])
    @district = District.find_by("id = ?", params[:trip][:district_id])
  end

  def update_cities
    @cities = City.where("country_id = ?", params[:country_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def update_districts
    @districts = District.where("city_id = ?", params[:city_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the `index.html` file;

```
<%= form_for :trip, url: {action: "show"}, html: {method: "get"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :country_id, options_for_select(@countries.collect { |country|
    [country.name.titleize, country.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'countries_select' } %>

  <%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@cities.collect { |city|
    [city.name.titleize, city.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'cities_select' } %>

 <%= f.select :district_id, options_for_select(@districts.collect { |district|
    [district.name.titleize, district.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'district_select' } %>
  <%= f.submit "Go!" %>
<% end %>
```

And the partial for the index `districts/_district.html.erb`

```
<option value="<%= district.id %>"><%= district.name.titleize %></option>
```

And `cities/_city.html.erb`

```
<option value="<%= city.id %>"><%= city.name.titleize %></option>
```

Lastly, the `welcome.coffee`

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#countries_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_cities',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        country_id: $("#countries_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")


$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#cities_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_districts',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        city_id: $("#cities_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

I do not know where I am doing wrong as it seems working but having troubles with the view. So it might be the `<option>` tag But could not find it.

Thank you very much for your help